# Let $f:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth map with $df_x \neq 0$, for all $x \in S^1$.

Tags: differential-topology

Let $f:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth map with $df_x \neq 0$, for all $x \in S^1$.  Show that there is a plane $C$ through the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $p\circ f:S^1\rightarrow C$ has $d(p\circ f)_x \neq 0$, for all $x \in S^1$, where $p$ denotes orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $C$.

Comment: Is this homework? What do you know and what have you tried?

Comment: Surely there exists a better title...

Comment: How could this be homework whenever it is summer?

Comment: @dunkindonuts It's winter in the Southern hemisphere...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $g$ that sends any $x\in S^1$ to the unit tangent vector to the curve $f$ at $x$ (up to notational issues, $g(x)=df_x/\Vert df_x\Vert$).  This is a smooth map from $S^1$ to $S^2$.  So there is a vector $v\in S^2$ such that neither $v$ nor $-v$ is in the image of $g$.  Choose the plane $C$ to be perpendicular to such a $v$, so that your projection $p$ is in the direction of $v$.

Comment: Hence my reason for asking the background of the OP; he was too busy being snide to bother answering. Your "So there is ..." is quite a leap. One needs either Sard's Theorem or a good exercise on how the image of a smooth map from $\mathbb R^k$ to $\mathbb R^\ell$ with $k<\ell$ has measure $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was, indeed, making optimistic assumptions about the OP's background, not so much because I really believed those assumptions but because they made possible a rather short answer. I figured that, if the OP comes back and says he doesn't follow this short answer, then I or someone else can amplify it.